# When my pc executes the code below why does it starts with 5?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, printing, while-loop

I'm a newbie to c++.

I want my pc to count for about 100 times (the amount doesn't really matter) from 1 to 10 and to print each time the current value.

When I remove (put it in comment) the "while" loop the pc starts to count from 1. But when I add the while loop again the pc starts with 5. It gets even more mysterious to me when I execute the code a few times. Than pc starts with 6 :s

I've searched the internet with Google and Duckduckgo but I couldn't find a similar question. Nor in the questions already asked in Stackoverflow.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a=0;
int b=1;

int main()
{
    while(b<100){

        for(a=1;a<=10;a++){
            cout << a << endl;
        }

        a=1;
        b++;
    }

    cout<<b <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Result from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3vxm.png)

Comment: [Can't replicate](http://ideone.com/5ol83y). Is the scrollbar at the top? How big is your output buffer in the window, maybe it's not big enough to fit all lines so the first ones are lost?

Comment: The terminal you are using to view ("DOS window") only has a limited amount of scrollback. The lines before simply got lost and cannot be reached by scrolling up, because it will only save a certain amount of lines for you to view. If you try a different terminal emulator (I guess you’re out of luck there on windows) or run the program e.g. [on ideone](https://ideone.com/gDr3Yg), you will see that your program is doing what you expect, only what you use to view the results does not behave as you expect.

Comment: [Windows Command Prompt: How do I increase my buffer?](http://superuser.com/questions/378313/windows-command-prompt-how-do-i-increase-my-buffer)

Comment: Print Horizontally :)

Comment: That might also solve it, thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact there is nothing wrong with your code.  The output you have kindly provided as a screenshot shows the top of your terminal showing 5 or 6, but this is only because your program produces some 991 lines of output, which is presumably overflowing your terminal scrollback buffer.

Try changing the while loop from `100` to `3` and see if it works.  It will.

Comment: Thank you :D
That solved it ^^